# import not found

Tags: haskell

This program is about counting words but it gives an error in the header and I couldn't fix it. The compiler it said not found and asked me to use `-v` but this also gives an error. What are the other files that I need to use for vectors?

Here's the code I'm trying to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, MagicHash #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Data.Vector.Unboxed ((!))
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as VG --this one 
import GHC.Base (Int(..), quotInt#, remInt#)

ones, tens, teens :: [String]
ones = ["", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
tens = ["", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
teens = ["ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
 "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]

wordify :: Int -> String
wordify n
    | n < 10         = ones !! n
    | n < 20         = teens !! (n-10)
    | n < 100        = splitterTen
    | n < 1000       = splitter 100 "hundred"
    | n < 1000000    = splitter 1000 "thousand"
    | otherwise      = splitter 1000000 "million"
      where 
         splitterTen = let (t, x) = n `quotRem` 10 
                       in (tens !! t) ++ wordify x
         splitter d suffix = let (t, x) = n `quotRem` d
                             in (wordify t) ++ suffix ++ wordify x

wordLength :: Int -> Int
wordLength i = go 0 i
  where
    go !pad !n
        | n < 10         = lenOnes `VG.unsafeIndex` n + pad
        | n < 20         = lenTeens `VG.unsafeIndex` (n-10) + pad
        | n < 100        = go (lenTens `VG.unsafeIndex` (n//10) + pad) (n%10)
        | n < 1000       = go (go (7+pad) (n//100)) (n%100)
        | n < 1000000    = go (go (8+pad) (n//1000)) (n%1000)
        | otherwise      = go (go (7+pad) (n//1000000)) (n%1000000)

    (I# a) // (I# b) = I# (a `quotInt#` b)
    (I# a) % (I# b) = I# (a `remInt#` b)
    !lenOnes = VU.fromList [0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4] -- "", "one","two", ...
    !lenTens = VU.fromList [0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6]
    !lenTeens = VU.fromList [3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8] -- first element is "ten" 3
```

Comment: You should add to your question the error you get, the command line you use to compile and/or run the code and the OS you use.

Comment: Also you should add the version of your compiler.

Comment: the error is  Could not find module `Data.Vector.Generic'
 Use -v to see a list of the files searched for. my os is windows my compiler is ghci 2012.2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

It seems you

1. Miss extensions
2. Have broken indentation

Here is a fixed version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, BangPatterns #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Data.Vector.Unboxed ((!))
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as VG --this once 
import GHC.Base (Int(..), quotInt#, remInt#)

ones, tens, teens :: [String]
ones = ["", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
tens = ["", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
teens = ["ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eig  hteen", "nineteen"]

wordify :: Int -> String
wordify n
 | n < 10         = ones !! n
 | n < 20         = teens !! (n-10)
 | n < 100        = splitterTen
 | n < 1000       = splitter 100 "hundred"
 | n < 1000000    = splitter 1000 "thousand"
 | otherwise      = splitter 1000000 "million"
  where
   splitterTen = let (t, x) = n `quotRem` 10 
    in (tens !! t) ++ wordify x
   splitter d suffix = let (t, x) = n `quotRem` d
    in (wordify t) ++ suffix ++ wordify x

wordLength :: Int -> Int
wordLength i = go 0 i
  where
   go !pad !n
    | n < 10         = lenOnes `VG.unsafeIndex` n + pad
    | n < 20         = lenTeens `VG.unsafeIndex` (n-10) + pad
    | n < 100        = go (lenTens `VG.unsafeIndex` (n//10) + pad) (n%10)
    | n < 1000       = go (go (7+pad) (n//100)) (n%100)
    | n < 1000000    = go (go (8+pad) (n//1000)) (n%1000)
    | otherwise      = go (go (7+pad) (n//1000000)) (n%1000000)

   (I# a) // (I# b) = I# (a `quotInt#` b)
   (I# a) % (I# b) = I# (a `remInt#` b)
   !lenOnes = VU.fromList [0,3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4] -- "", "one","two", ...
   !lenTens = VU.fromList [0,3,6,6,5,5,5,7,6,6]
   !lenTeens = VU.fromList [3,6,6,8,8,7,7,9,8,8] -- first element is "ten" 3
```

Note the fixed indents and `LANGUAGE` pragma in the beginning to indicate that you use
two non-standard language extensions.

You can run `ghc-pkg vector` and if it doesn't say something like `vector-0.9.1` then you need to run `cabal update` followed by `cabal install vector`.

Comment: See http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/wiki/CabalInstall . It's the library installer for Haskell. It comes with Haskell Platform. If `ghc-pkg vector` failed to show the library version - it means you don't have vector library installed and must install it. Running `cabal install {library name}` is the preferred way to install libraries.

Comment: @user1664205 You execute cabal commands on the command line (in a terminal).  If you don't have cabal installed then I suggest you either use your package manager (on linux: apt-get, yum, etc on mac: port or homebrew) or for Windows you download the cabal tarball (see the link nponeccop provided) and install it manually.